# Socket.io & Node.js -- Change the JS file that socket references

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am new to node.js/socket.io, and I'm wondering how to get my index.html file, which loads correctly, to reference the chat-server.js file correctly.

My file structure looks like this:

- css
- js
- node-modules
- static

  - index.html
- chat-server.js

...

Thank you

Comment: Why does your *public* ``index.html`` file have to access your *private* server file?

Comment: It seems that maybe you don't realize that your client Javascript files run in the browser on the browser's computer and your server Javascript files run on your server.  They cannot directly access each other.  If you want to send or retrieve data from the server, then you would either send a socket.io message (in either direction) or make an Ajax call from the browser to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [express](https://expressjs.com/) middleware

```
app.use(express.static('static'))
```

Another way to do is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html loads properly, your express application serves static resources properly. It seems that 'static' content is served from 'static' directory, and client side scripts (one of which I believe you are trying to load) loaded via `<script src="my_script.js"></script>` are static assets. Thus, you have to move your `chat-server.js` to 'static' directory.